Stochastic Integral and Ito's Isometry: Sharp-bracket process [M] or Angle-bracket process <M>?
I am learning stochastic integral, and I have noticed that the Ito's Isometry is sometimes stated using the quadratic variation process $[M]$ (e.g., pg. 47, Eq. (27.3), vol. 2 of Rogers & William), and sometimes using the predictable quadratic variation process $\langle M\rangle$ (e.g., Chap. 6.5 of Hui-Hsiung Kuo).
I understand that the Isometry holds for both $[M]$ and $\langle M\rangle$, since the crucial equality
$$E[(M_t- M_s)^2 |\mathcal{F}_s]=E[[M]_t-[M]_s|\mathcal{F}_s] = E[\langle M\rangle_t-\langle M\rangle_s|\mathcal{F}_s]$$
holds for both $[M]$ and $\langle M\rangle$ (both $M^2-[M]$ and $M^2-\langle M\rangle$ are martingales).
I also understand the difference between $[M]$ and $\langle M\rangle$ (e.g., $\langle M\rangle$ is the dual predictable projection of $[M]$, so that they coincide only for continuous martingales. However, $\langle M\rangle$ is restricted to locally square integrable martingales whereas $[M]$ can be defined for any local martingale). Moreover, I read a pedagogical paper  which says that Meyer first introduced the $\langle M\rangle$ process for defining stochastic integration, then introduced the $[M]$ via $\langle M^c\rangle$ and $\Delta \langle M\rangle$ (where $M^c$ is the continuous part of $M$).
Can someone familar with the literature explains why we need two bracket processes? Is that because $[M]$ is more general than $\langle M\rangle$ so that we can define stochastic integral w.r.t. more general semimartingales? If restricted to stochastic integral w.r.t. (local) martingale, is there any difference between the integral defined via $\langle M\rangle$ and $[M]$?
A brief introduction to the history of the development of stochastic integral will be greatly appreciated.
